# Injecting ParseUser object to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, parse-platform

I'm trying to use parse's .net client in an mvc web application.
and couldn't find a proper way to inject **ParseObject**, **ParseUser** and **ParseUser.CurrentUser**

what is the nice way of injecting static objects?

web app has a Forms authentication setup.
and ioc container register components or services LifestylePerWebRequest()

my problem occured when I want to update the user object,
only if the ParseUser.CurrentUser logged in we can update. (https://parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#users-security)

but this is a static object and I get the latest signed in user...

now I'm thinking to create a user2 table in parse and keep all profile data in there...

Is there a better way to go?

```
    public async Task<bool> UpdateUser(string id, string name, string surname)
    {
        //var user = ParseUser.CurrentUser;

        var user = await ParseUser.Query.GetAsync(id);
        if (user == null) return await Task.FromResult(false);

        user.Name = name;
        user.Surname = surname;
        await user.SaveAsync();

        return await Task.FromResult(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> what is the nice way of injecting static objects?

You hide them behind an application-defined abstraction. You define [a narrow interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) that describes the functionality that your application needs (and ideally without the interface leaking the external framework). For instance:

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    // Throws an exception on failure.
    void UpdateUser(string id, string name, string surname);
}
```

Now you can hide the static class behind an implementation of `IUserRepository`:

```
public class ParseUserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public void UpdateUser(string id, string name, string surname)
    {
        // call the static Parse functionality.
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for guidance, here when i call the static parse functionality to update user table, it wants the currentuser to be authenticated. and it is my problem that can't be solved...